# Android:Will the size of image affect the processing time of SURF

Tags: java, android, image-processing, opencv, surf

Since SURF feature matching spend a lot of processing time. So I decided to resize the bitmap in order to shorten the processing time of SURF.But can I know if make the bitmap smaller will spend less processing time of SURF?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, that's one way to speed up most image processing algorithms.

In OpenCV, you can also specify the parameters `_nOctaveLayers` and `_nOctaves` in the `SURF` constructor.  These parameters dictate the number of different scales that the algorithm checks for feature points.  If you decrease these, you will get a faster detection time, but you will also miss out on feature points at scales that aren't checked.

These speedups are based around the *detection* of `SURF` points.  If you are talking strictly about matching the points, then it is the number of points in the image that is the largest dictator of the running time.

Comment: Thanks for your response.So speed up the SURF will decrease the accuracy?But accuracy is also very important for such matching application.Since the processing time is based on detection of SURF point,so resize the image will not speed up the image processing?Am I right?

Comment: It isn't guaranteed to reduce the accuracy, but that's a likely outcome.  It's the most infamous problem in computer vision: speed versus accuracy.  Another alternative for you may be OpenCV's GPU implementation of SURF

Answer (score 0):

have you tried orb? you can find orb sample usage under samples/python2/plane_tracker.py. i havent tried it on phone but on pc it can match many targets simultaneously and quickly while surf is struggling with just one.